# How to create an Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy to SharePoint?

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint, azure-pipelines

What I would like to do is whenever a commit is pushed into a stable branch, a pipeline would copy the **code** directly into a SharePoint folder.

I'm new to Azure DevOps and finding difficult to find the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PowerShell with [SharePointPnP.PowerShell](https://github.com/pnp/powershell) to copy files to SharePoint folder.

On Azure DevOps you need to create new **release** pipeline with run Powershell script task.
If it is SharePoint on-premise, it should be accessible from internet of course.

Comment: Confirmed this is a viable approach in my own pipelines.

Comment: This approach is not working as office 365cli needed and publish is not working at all using copy or publish task at all

Comment: Step to install CLI in a pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/implement-ci-cd-with-azure-devops#installing-the-cli-for-microsoft-365